# Yii Lazy Loading

Tags: php, yii

How do you use lazy loading correctly in Yii? I have two models, Company and Settings. The relationship is defined at Company side with:

```
'settings' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Company', 'settingsId'),
```

and at Settings side with:

```
'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'settingsId'),
```

Now, why does this not work in the Company model:

```
$settings = $this->settings;
echo $settings->someSetting;
```

The error is

```
Property "Company.someSetting" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't be that Company has one Settings?

```
'settings' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Settings', 'settingsId'),
```